# What's the record for total commercial flight-hours?

Tags: logging, airline-pilot

Which airline pilot has the record for the highest number of total airline flight hours globally?

I found an article on [Ed Long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Long_(aviator)) who had over 65,000 hours, but I'm only interested in airline pilots (also, most of his hours were at an altitude of under 200ft...)

Comment: You may not have known it, but commercial pilots are limited by the number of commercial hours flown in a week/month/year, see: [What is common number of flight hours a year for an airline pilot?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1807/14897) Knowing this, the record would be moot and hard to corroborate (small margins). I don't think it can be answered factually.

Comment: @ymb1 Sure, I guess then it's whoever started the youngest and retired the latest... would still be interested in a name / number if it's possible.

Comment: @ymb1: limits are just about most commercial flights, not all.I remember seeing a documentary about a pilots flight commercial flights (freight/post) on some GB islands, single pilot flights, and as i understood, on such flight: no passengers, small aircraft, there are no limits. So the question should be clarified.

Comment: Are you asking for total flight hours for a commercial pilot or total hours flown only commercially by a pilot as I'm not sure you'd be able to find sources for this given the "shape" of most commercial pilots careers.

Comment: @SteveMatthews Total flight hours flown commercially, (carrying paying pax basically)

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39193/62)

Comment: @Cloud all commercial airline (part 121) pilots have to retire at the same age so its really about who starts the youngest.

Comment: Dunno, though I do have a friend who retired from UAL with over 35,000 logged flight hours!

Comment: Let's remember that Commercial Pilots are not the same thing as Airline Pilots. Commercial Pilots are generally not limited to flight time except as flight instructors or charter pilots, whereas Airline Pilots are limited in their Airline or charter flying. At least under FAA regulations, airline flying is more limited than charter flying. Charter pilots can fly up to 1200 hrs per year.